# Listar arquivos ignorados com git --assume change

Tags: git

Ignorei alguns arquivos em um projeto git e preciso apenas ter o controle pra saber quais foram ignorados ou não. Vai que em algum momento eu precise mudar.
Já tentei todos os comandos abaixo:

```
 1116  git --index-info
 1117  git check-ignore
 1119  git check-ignore ./
 1120  git ls-files -i
 1121  cat .git/ignore
 1122  cat .git/index 
 1123  git ls-files --others -i --exclude-standard
```

Desde já agradeço a ajuda..

Comment: Olá Rafael, você não gostaria de postar um mini-exemplo de comandos que você rodou para "ignorar" arquivos? Eu geralmente edito o arquivo `.gitignore` para ignorar determinado arquivo, e visualizo *patterns* ignorados listado o conteúdo do arquivo `cat .gitignore`, mas não sei se estou falando da mesma coisa que você.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma forma simples é executar o comando **git clean -ndX**, que exibirá uma prévia dos arquivos que seriam removidos pelo comando sem o parâmetro -n.

Se quiser entender mais esse comando e como essa parametrização te ajuda nessa situação, veja o manual do comando no site do Git: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean

Answer (score 0):

A partir da versão 1.7.6, basta utilizar o comando: **git status --ignored**